# how to do grouping of the data.I want to show a list which on click contains data of foo and on click of it data of boo

Tags: c#

I have a resobject with structure like this.

```
public class resobject
{
    public IList<foo> Foo{get;set}
    public string message{get;set;}
}

public class foo
{
    public IList<boo> Boo{get;set}
}

public class boo
{
    public string category{get;set;}
}
```

currently i am having resobject data.How to reach to boo class and access the data.

Comment: Foo(index).Boo ...sounds funny foo dot boo

Comment: Though the Property Foo.

Comment: You can't just get 'boo' directly, though.  You need to make sure it passes a certain threshold - namely, that IList<boo> Boo has an instance and is populated.  I'd suggest adding a 'bar' property to hold this.  Also, you probably want 'category' to be private with a public accessor - for consistency's sake you should call this 'hoo'.  So your final code should look something like  if (foo.bar) return boo.hoo;  </sarc>

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Program
{

    public class resobject
    {   
        public IList<foo> Foo{get;set;}
        public string message{get;set;}
    }

    public class foo
    {
        public IList<boo> Boo{get;set;}
    }

    public class boo
    {
        public string category{get;set;}
    }



    public static void Main()
    {
        var root = new resobject();

        foreach(var f in root.Foo)
        {
            foreach(var b in f.Boo)
            {
                b.category = "value";
            }
        }
    }
}
```